# jQuery Animate Dynamic Transformation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, translate-animation

I am new to jQuery and am building a basic block which moves left, if I press left; move right if I press right. It works perfectly. However, instead of using css webkitTransform directly, I would like to use animation to make the movement smoother. Here is my initial code: http://jsfiddle.net/hphchan/c2zzhjwL/.

I have been browsing how to do this all day, but still cannot reach the answer. I notice there is a `.animate()` built-in method of jQuery and `step` function. However, I do not know how to do it to make it works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `.animate` you can replace

`$spinner.css("webkitTransform", "translate(" + i + "px, 0)");`

with

```
$spinner.animate({ left: i }, {
       duration: 500, //change this according to your need
       step: function(now, fx){
            $spinner.css("margin-left", now);
       }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/c2zzhjwL/3/)**

> **[Article](http://cdmckay.org/blog/2010/03/01/the-jquery-animate-step-callback-function/)** if you want more in detail

Comment: are there any alternative methods... ???
it seems that this method cannot create a smooth enough translation... like a normal CSS translation do... 
for example: http://jsfiddle.net/hphchan/pmgn2q5e/1/

Comment: @CHANist in that case you can try increasing `i` value to higher one because that's how `animation` and `step` works. See this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/c2zzhjwL/8/)**

Answer (score 0):

You have very less time to animate the spinner, I would suggest use CSS to achive the same result here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/c2zzhjwL/5/).

```
#spinner {
   width : 50px;
   height : 10px;
   background-color : #000;
   -webkit-transition: all .6s; /* Safari */
   transition: all .6s;
}
```

Comment: You can achive smoother animation than jQuery animate method

Answer (score 0):

With animate you can use :

```
$spinner.animate({
    left: i
}, 200);
```

For this, you must set the position of your `#spinner` to relative or absolute. If you want to create a game this will be useful for the hitboxs.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/c2zzhjwL/6/)